# Redirect different domains pointing to same server to different version of same website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have different domains say like (fictious names) "plumbers.org" and "cleaning.org"
pointing to the same folder in my apache2 conf.
and the main domain is "workers.org"

what i want to obtain is basically to have `plumbers.org` pointing to `workers.org/index.php?version=1`

and to have `cleaning.org` pointing to `workers.org/index.php?version=2`

is something I set in my .htacess? what's best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add a permanent redirect in the original httpd / apache conf file, e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
    ServerName plumbers.org
    Redirect 301 / http://workers.org/index.php?version=1
</VirtualHost>

...

<VirtualHost ...>
    ServerName cleaning.org
    Redirect 301 / http://workers.org/index.php?version=2
</VirtualHost>
```

Technically, it should also work if you put these changes in the corresponding .htaccess files (if .htaccess files are not prohibited by the "parent" conf). Without `<VirtualHost>` section, of course, then.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all 3 domains point to the same `DocumentRoot` folder, you can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)plumbers\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?version=1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)cleaning\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?version=2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hmm your accepted question is doing an external redirect and changing URL in browser to `http://workers.org/index.php?version=1` or `http://workers.org/index.php?version=2`